# Is it possible to top up smart contract's balance at the time of its deployment?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, rsk

Say I have a Solidity smart contract `MultiToken.sol` which I am developing and testing using [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) and deploying to the [RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/) network.
​

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
​
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
​
contract MultiToken is ERC1155 {
    constructor(string memory uri) ERC1155(uri) {}
}
```

​
I am deploying the smart contract in the tests `before` section:
​

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
​
describe('MultiToken', () => {
  let multiToken;
​
  const uri = 'https://token-cdn-domain/{id}.json';
​
  before(async () => {
    const factory = await ethers.getContractFactory('MultiToken');
    multiToken = await factory.deploy(uri);
    await multiToken.deployed();
  });
​
  it('MultiToken URI must be correct', async () => {
    const multiTokenUri = await multiToken.uri(0);
    expect(multiTokenUri).to.equal(uri);
  });
});
```

​
I would like to be able to transfer some [RBTC](https://www.rsk.co/rbtc/) to my smart contract's address during the deployment transaction. Is it possible to top up smart contract's balance at the time of its deployment using Hardhat and Ethers?
​
Specifically, can I do this with a *single transaction*?
​
For reference, this is my `hardhat.config.js`:
​

```js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
const { mnemonic } = require('./.secret.json');
​
module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.4',
  defaultNetwork: 'rskregtest',
  networks: {
    rskregtest: {
      url: 'http://localhost:4444',
      chainId: 33,
    },
    rsktestnet: {
      chainId: 31,
      url: 'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/',
      accounts: {
        mnemonic,
        path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare the `constructor` as `payable`, and then override the `value` param (default value 0) of the deploying transaction.

```
contract MultiToken is ERC1155 {
    constructor(string memory uri) ERC1155(uri) payable {}
}
```

```
multiToken = await factory.deploy(uri, {
    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1"), // 1 RBTC to wei
});
```

Docs:

- https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/cheatsheet.html?highlight=payable#modifiers
- https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseUnits
- https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/#ContractFactory-deploy